# How to create reducer and action from mapped variable from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have this working in vanilla react component state but I am incorporating it into Redux now and the question is, how would I go about feeding a mapped item variable into a reducer or action file? Here is some code to give you an idea.

Here is the functions in question that I want to convert to Redux.

```
this.handleShow = (food) => {
  this.setState({activefood:food}, ()=> this.setState({ show: true }));
};

this.handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({ show: false });
};
```

Heres the map

```
 {foodReducer.map(food => (
                <li key={food._id}>
                    <div className="description">
                       <button onClick={()=> this.handleShow(food.foodname)}> 
                            <h4>{food.foodname}</h4>
                         </button>
                    </div> 
                </li>

                ))}
```

So, its basically a click function that when a food from a mapped list is clicked, a modal pops up with
the actual name of the food that was clicked rendered in the modal. But `activefood` state takes in `food` from the map so how would the reducer or the action file know or recognize what that variable is? I want to know if its possible and what direction or steps I should take. thanks.

Comment: do you mean to add food names to the redux store? also, do you know things about redux or you are a newbie?

Comment: Not really sure but it'll be interesting to see what you mean. I know 'things' about redux. I already have my store, reducer and action files in use via redux. I just haven't come across this problem before. Thanks